# php image resize function not retaining quality of image

Tags: php, image

I was working on a functioning to resize an image. Upon upload it would go through a script to make a copy but the resized copy is coming back with worse quality. I was wondering if anyone could take a look to see where I went wrong. The image gets to be the correct size but it looks pixelated.

php form:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="image_upload_script.php">
Choose your file here:
<input name="uploaded_file" type="file"/><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload It"/>
</form>
```

image_upload_script:

```
   <?php
// Access the $_FILES global variable for this specific file being uploaded
// and create local PHP variables from the $_FILES array of information
$fileName = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
$kaboom = explode(".", $fileName); // Split file name into an array using the dot
$fileExt = end($kaboom); // Now target the last array element to get the file extension
// START PHP Image Upload Error Handling --------------------------------------------------
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
} else if($fileSize > 5242880) { // if file size is larger than 5 Megabytes
    echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 5 Megabytes in size.";
    unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
    exit();
} else if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {
     // This condition is only if you wish to allow uploading of specific file types    
     echo "ERROR: Your image was not .gif, .jpg, or .png.";
     unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
     exit();
} else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) { // if file upload error key is equal to 1
    echo "ERROR: An error occured while processing the file. Try again.";
    exit();
}
// END PHP Image Upload Error Handling ----------------------------------------------------
// Place it into your "uploads" folder mow using the move_uploaded_file() function
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName");
// Check to make sure the move result is true before continuing
if ($moveResult != true) {
    echo "ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.";
    unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
    exit();
}
unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
// ---------- Include Universal Image Resizing Function --------
include_once("resize.php");
$target_file = "uploads/$fileName";
$resized_file = "uploads/resized_$fileName";
$wmax = 84;
$hmax = 78;
resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $fileExt);
// ----------- End Universal Image Resizing Function -----------
// Display things to the page so you can see what is happening for testing purposes
echo "The file named <strong>$fileName</strong> uploaded successfuly.<br /><br />";
echo "It is <strong>$fileSize</strong> bytes in size.<br /><br />";
echo "It is an <strong>$fileType</strong> type of file.<br /><br />";
echo "The file extension is <strong>$fileExt</strong><br /><br />";
echo "The Error Message output for this upload is: $fileErrorMsg";
?>
```

resize.php:

```
    <?php
// Function for resizing jpg, gif, or png image files
function resize($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {
    list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
    $scale_ratio = $w_orig / $h_orig;
    if (($w / $h) > $scale_ratio) {
           $w = $h * $scale_ratio;
    } else {
           $h = $w / $scale_ratio;
    }
    $img = "";
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    if ($ext == "gif"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
    } else if($ext =="png"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
    } else { 
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    }
    $tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    // imagecopyresampled(dst_img, src_img, dst_x, dst_y, src_x, src_y, dst_w, dst_h, src_w, src_h)
    imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
    imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 80);
}
?>
```

All feedback welcomed and thank you.

Comment: if you are making the image bigger you will always loose quality

Comment: I am making it smaller would it lose quality as well?

Comment: Try `imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 100);`

Comment: If you could post a link with the two images, including their sizes. It may be that you are trying to make the image bigger which will result in lower quality

Comment: original image is 2162 × 3248 and I am converting it to 84 x 78

Comment: I tried the imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 100); but it renders the same quality issue

Comment: @Blanco- With that dramatic of a change (smaller) in size that you are making, it is very likely that you will lose quality (it will depend on the complexity of the image).   Perhaps try shrinking it in 2 or more stages:  first to 1081 x 1624, then to 540 x 812, etc.

Comment: @DaveOlson Yes I think the size difference is just too much it still gets pixelated I went from the original size to 300 x 300 and it looks decent any smaller and pixels are clearly seen

Comment: @Blanco - You are also making a (significant) change to the aspect ratio:  from "tall and thin" to nearly square.  See what 86 x 129 (25x smaller in both dimensions) gets you;  and you still may need to do it in stages.